# If the minifyEnabled feature is set to true, I'm getting a null pointer exception inside the SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook

The current --keep configurations i'm using are:

```
-keepattributes Signature 

-keepattributes Exceptions 

-keep class com.loginradius.** { *; }
```

With this settings, everything's working fine, but it does not minify or obfuscate the code of the SDK, and all of our classes that have a reference to it, leaving it exposed in case I decompile or reverse engineer the apk. We know there are some issues if you minify the classes that override a javascript interfaces, but even if you specify the classes that override them, like in the following example, it still gives us the null pointer exception. 
E.g:

```
-keep class com.loginradius.sdk.ui.WebLogin** { *; } 
-keep class com.loginradius.userregistration.LoginRadiusRaas** { *; } 
-keep class com.loginradius.userregistration.LoginRadiusUserReg** { *; } 
-keep class com.loginradius.userregistration.WebClient** { *; }`enter code here`
```

Here's the full stack of both errors:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference 
at com.nyxtechnology.app.telegana.controller.sessions.FbLoginActivity$1.onSuccess(FbLoginActivity.java:47) 
at com.nyxtechnology.app.telegana.controller.sessions.FbLoginActivity$1.onSuccess(FbLoginActivity.java:44) 
at com.nyxtechnology.app.loginradius.sdk.ui.lrLoginManager$3.onSuccess(lrLoginManager.java:214) 
at com.nyxtechnology.app.loginradius.sdk.ui.lrLoginManager$3.onSuccess(lrLoginManager.java:210) 
at com.nyxtechnology.app.loginradius.sdk.util.RestRequest$1.onSuccess(RestRequest.java:36) 
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:117) 
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleSuccessMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:168) 
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:184) 
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$1.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:84) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.nyxtechnology.app.loginradius.sdk.models.lrAccessToken.provider' on a null object reference 
at com.nyxtechnology.app.loginradius.sdk.api.UserProfileAPI.getResponse(UserProfileAPI.java:32) 
at com.nyxtechnology.app.telegana.controller.networks.SecureRequestManager.getUserDataFromFB(SecureRequestManager.java:312) 
at com.nyxtechnology.app.telegana.controller.engine.EngineServiceUiCallbacks$9$2.onClick(EngineServiceUiCallbacks.java:309) 
at cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog.onClick(SweetAlertDialog.java:372) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6843) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```